# How to access the first and the last elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Before posting, I have already gone through [Access an arbitrary element in a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097866/python-access-to-first-element-in-dictionary), but I'm uncertain about this.

I have a long dictionary and I've to get the values of its first and last keys. I can use `dict[dict.keys()[0]]` and `dict[dict.keys()[-1]]` to get the first and last elements, but since the key:value pairs are outputted in a random form(as in the positioning of the key:value pairs is random), will the solution provided in this link always work?

Comment: If d is a dict, In Python 3, d.keys() is an iterable rather than a list, so dict.keys()[-1] doesn't work.  In Python 3.7+, next(reversed(d.keys())) does work, but more important, next(reversed(d.values())) gets you the last-added value in constant time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), because a normal dictionary doesn't preserve the insertion order of its elements when traversing it. Here's how:

```
# import the right class
from collections import OrderedDict

# create and fill the dictionary
d = OrderedDict()
d['first']  = 1
d['second'] = 2
d['third']  = 3

# retrieve key/value pairs
els = list(d.items()) # explicitly convert to a list, in case it's Python 3.x

# get first inserted element 
els[0]
=> ('first', 1)

# get last inserted element 
els[-1]
=> ('third', 3)
```

Comment: As of Python 3.6 OrderDict() is no longer necessary, because the current native dictionary implementation preserves insertion order.

Comment: @juanIsaza Can you provide a proof link please?!

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without having to copy the entire dictionary content to a list? Something like d.front() and d.back() ?

Comment: @TechJS I updated his answer with a link to the documentation and some quotes for proof.

Answer (score 23):

If working with Python 3.6+ you can do a one liner:

First:

```
list({'fist': 1, 'second': 2, 'last': 3}.items())[0]
=> ('first', 1)
```

Last:

```
list({'fist': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}.items())[-1]
=> ('third', 1)
```

This is the case because Python 3.6+ default dictionary preserves insertion order. This is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end.

and

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Comment: Not necessarily safe to rely on standard dicts being ordered: http://gandenberger.org/2018/03/10/ordered-dicts-vs-ordereddict/

Comment: @fantabolous Off course Pandas and other libraries who predate Python3.6 won't assume any order, but still the language is evolving and you should embrace new ways of doing things or you get stuck in the past and in the end you loose productivity.

Answer (score 6):

With OrderedDict you can use [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-iterator)

```
d = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
next(iter(d)) # returns 'a'
next(reversed(d) # returns 'c'
```

Comment: This works with a regular dict in Python 3.7+. As far as I can see, this is the only CONSTANT-TIME way to get the last element of a dict (in Python 3.7+) or DefaultDict before that.  The use of "reversed" may make people worry it constructs a list, or worse, sorts-- it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously it's too late to answer, yet I'd like to add the following to the awesome answers above

```py
dct = {"first": 1, "second": 2, "last": 3}

first, *_, last = dct.items()
print("*** Items ***")
print("First Item:", first)
print("Last Item:", last)

first, *_, last = dct.keys()
print("*** Keys ***")
print("First Key:", first)
print("Last Key:", last)

first, *_, last = dct.values()
print("*** Values ***")
print("First Value:", first)
print("Last Value:", last)
```

```sh
*** Items ***
First Item: ('first', 1)
Last Item: ('last', 3)

*** Keys ***
First Key: first
Last Key: last

*** Values ***
First Value: 1
Last Value: 3
```

Comment: This is so much easier than converting the dictionary to a list.

Comment: @Tes3awy, that does convert all but the first and last elements to the list _ (underscore by itself is a Python variable name). I've confirmed this with a longer dictionary in Python 3.10

Comment: @SteveWithamDuplicate Yes, it does convert the elements in between the first and the last.

Comment: @SteveWithamDuplicate But what is the problem here?

Comment: Hi, @Tes3awy, it's just that howdoicode said it's "easier than converting the dictionary to a list."  And since it *is* converting the dictionary to a list, that means two things: 1) That's how easy it is to convert a dictionary to a list in Python, and 2) If the dictionary is large, this would be a costly way to get one element out of it.  So, since howdoicode didn't understand that, it could cause a problem in practice for them.  Especially because one *can* get the first and last items *without* converting to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are unordered, so "first" and "last" isn't defined.  Instead, you can sort your keys, and then access the element associated with the first and last key in your sorted set.

EDIT:

The OP clarified that by "first" and "last" he meant the order in which keys were added to the dictionary.  `collections.OrderedDict` should work for this case.

Comment: Thats what I said. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @user1162512 I've added a suggestion for sorting the keys, but that's the best you can do.

Comment: What if I store my dictionary as `dict= {"xyz":294,"a":1,"rah":129}`. On what basis would I sort the keys in order to get the access of xyz and rah.

Comment: PS: I dont want to search using dict["xyz"]

Comment: @user1162512: the second you write `{"xyz":294,"a":1,"rah":129}`, you've lost any information about the order, because that's a dictionary literal.  As mentioned elsewhere in this thread, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` for an insertion-order variant.

Comment: @user1162512 As someone else commented, it depends what you meant by first and last.  If you mean first inserted (in terms of time), then collections.OrderedDict is the way to go.  I had assumed you meant first according to some ordering.

Comment: @user1162512 The solution is to use OrderedDict which does keep track of element order and has a perfectly defined first and last element.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "first" or "last" key in dictionary, which does not guarantee any particular ordering. So there is **no possibility** to get "first" or "last" element. You can only create your own wrapper around python dict, which will store the information about "first" and "last" object

Something like

```
class MyDict:

  def __init__(self):
    self.first=None
    self.last=None
    self.dict={}

  def add( key, value ):
    if self.first==None: self.first=key
    self.last=key
    self.dict[key]=value

  def get( key ):
    return self.dict[key]

  def first():
    return self.dict[ self.first ]

  def last():
    return self.dict[ self.last ]
```

Although as it was pointed out in the comment there is already a class `OrderedDict`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember
>   the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered
>   dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first
>   added.

Comment: Or use ``collections.OrderedDict``, if its definition of "first" and "last" coincides with OP's.

Comment: And how will I create a wrapper? Any demo?

Comment: Since Python 3.7 there is a defined first and last element of every standard dictionary.  That is, dict is now *defined* to act like OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using list().

```
dir = dict()

dir['Key-3'] = 'Value-3'    # Added First Item
dir['Key-2'] = 'Value-2'    # Added Second Item
dir['Key-4'] = 'Value-4'    # Added Third Item
dir['Key-1'] = 'Value-1'    # Added Fourth Item

lst = list(dir.items())     # For key & value
# lst = list(dir.keys())    # For keys
# lst = list(dir.values())  # For values

print('First Element:- ', lst[0])
print('Last Element:- ', lst[-1])
```

Output:-

First Element:-  ('Key-3', 'Value-3')

Last Element:-  ('Key-1', 'Value-1')

Comment: Mind, only starting from python version 3.7 dictionary order is guaranteed to be equal to insertion order.

Answer (score -1):

def dictionarySortingExample(yourDictionary):

```
#get all the keys and store them to a list
allKeys = yourDictionary.keys()

#sort the list of keys
allKeysSorted = sorted(allKeys)

#retrieve the first and last keys in the list
firstKey = allKeysSorted[0]
lastKey = allKeysSorted[-1]

#retrive the values from the dictionary
firstValue = yourDictionary[firstKey]
lastValue = yourDictionary[lastKey]

print "---Sorted Dictionary---"
print "original dictionary: " + str(yourDictionary)
print "list of all keys: " + str(allKeys)
print "ordered list of all keys: " + str(allKeysSorted)
print "first item in sorted dictionary: " + str(firstKey) + ":" + str(firstValue)
print "last item in sorted dictionary: " + str(lastKey) + ":" + str(lastValue)
```

## example dictionary sorting

sampleDictionary = {4:"four", "Cranberry":2, 3:"three", 2:"two", "Apple":3, 1:"one", "Bananna":1}
dictionarySortingExample(sampleDictionary)