# Retrieving Last value of a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d={'Bat':1,'Tennisball':3,'Racquet':2,'Shuttlecock':3,'Javelin':1,'Soccer':1,'Hockey':7,'Gloves':8}
```

I want the last value of dictionary not key

Comment: best answer I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160064/6485674

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way, in *O(1)*, is to use [`dict.popitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem):

```
k, last_value = _, d[k] = d.popitem()
```

LIFO order is guaranteed since Python 3.7 (the same version when dictionary insertion ordering was guaranteed).

If the double assignment seems too tricky, consider

```
last_value = d[next(reversed(d))]
```

Here are the timing comparisons (CPython 3.10 on linux):

```
>>> d={'Bat':1,'Tennisball':3,'Racquet':2,'Shuttlecock':3,'Javelin':1,'Soccer':1,'Hockey':7,'Gloves':8}
>>> timeit k, last_value = _, d[k] = d.popitem()
107 ns ± 3.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> timeit next(reversed(d.values()))
150 ns ± 0.237 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> timeit d[next(reversed(d))]
134 ns ± 0.503 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: but this mutates the dict, which may not be desirable.

Comment: It doesn't mutate the dict.

Comment: Oh jeez, I did not notice `d[k] = ...` that's a little tricky.

Comment: @timgeb k was already hashed since it was in the dict previously.

Comment: This is very clever, instructive and thought-provoking solution, however, it's python, and I would prefer it to remain readable by humans.

Comment: Can you include `next(reversed(d_values))` in the timings? With `d_values = d.values()` in the setup. No reason to load and call that every time.

Comment: @KellyBundy it comes in at `119 ns ± 1.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)`

Comment: @pbuck For readability, I just put it inside a well-named function and documented it (+1 though, it is both clever and unreadable).

Answer (score 0):

For the last value you can use the code `print(list(d.values())[-1])` to turn the dictionary into a list of values, and then just get the last one with [-1].

Answer (score 0):

If your code relies on the last value you might have a design problem. While dicts are insertion-ordered in 3.7, their primary purpose is to map keys to values.

That being said, you can use

```
last = next(reversed(d.values()))
```

Note that `next` can take an optional fallback value in case your dictionary could be empty.

Comment: It's about 50% slower than dict.popitem, but it's probably still the best way if performance doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Python docs (v3.7+) say:

> Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used
> in the dictionary, in insertion order (if you want it sorted, just use
> sorted(d) instead). To check whether a single key is in the
> dictionary, use the in keyword.

Therefore `list(d)[-1]` results in final *key*, `d[list(d)[-1]]` will return final value.

Prior to python 3.7, dictionaries were unordered.

Comment: It's needlessly inefficient to convert the whole dict to a list of keys just to get the last key.

Comment: @wim also hashing the last key again

Comment: @timgeb Most objects, including strings, cache their hash value.

Comment: Apparently, even though converting to list is not desirable, it is actually performing faster than some of the results in @wim 's answer

Answer (score -2):

Look out for popitem(). It mutates (changes) the dict, despite some comments to the contrary. It may be the right solution, but it can create some issues if you aren't aware that the item popped disappears from the dict.

```
>>> d={'Bat':1,'Tennisball':3,'Racquet':2,'Shuttlecock':3,'Javelin':1,'Soccer':1,'Hockey':7,'Gloves':8}
>>> d
{'Bat': 1, 'Tennisball': 3, 'Racquet': 2, 'Shuttlecock': 3, 'Javelin': 1, 'Soccer': 1, 'Hockey': 7, 'Gloves': 8}
>>> d.popitem()
('Gloves', 8)
>>> d
{'Bat': 1, 'Tennisball': 3, 'Racquet': 2, 'Shuttlecock': 3, 'Javelin': 1, 'Soccer': 1, 'Hockey': 7}
```