# python: sorting 3 levels nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

my dictionary looks like:

```
     {modID1:{sequences1:{header1:count1},sequences2:{header2:count2}...},
      modID2:{sequences1:{header1:count1},sequences2:{header2:count2}...}....}
```

I want to reverse sort the "sequences" by "count", 
**example:**

```
{modID1:
    {sequences1:{header1: 3},sequences2:{header2:5},
     sequences3:  {header3:1}...},
modID2:{sequences1:{header1:1},sequences2:{header2:8},...},
....}
```

**Wanted output:**

```
{modID1:
  {sequences2:{header2:5},sequences1:{header1: 3},
   sequences3:{header3:1}...},
modID2:{sequences2:{header2:8},sequences1:{header1:1},...},
....}
```

I already saw some posts and I was trying to use something like:

```
 for k,v in Dic.iteritems():
    sorted=OrderedDict(sorted(v.iteritems(), key=lambda h: v[seq for seq in v][header], reverse=True))
```

But I guess I didn't get completely the usage of this function so is not working. Suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want an `OrderedDict` containing other `OrderedDict`s. At the moment you are creating an `OrderedDict` containing `dict`s

Comment: You also hide the `sorted` builtin by the assignment to `sorted`, so second time around the loop everything will break. And do you really have dictionaries of just a single key, value pair at the bottom - wouldn't a tuple do?

Comment: The {header:count} at the bottom is modified during the Dic creation, in practice the "count" starts from 1, and can increase. There is a way to maybe transform it in a tuple after Dic is created? Or I can modify the tuple from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python 3 example

```
d = {
"modID1":
    {
        "sequences1": {"header1": 3},
        "sequences2": {"header2": 5},
        "sequences3": {"header3": 1}
    },
"modID2":
    {
        "sequences1": {"header1": 1},
        "sequences2": {"header2": 8},
    },
}
result = {
    k: OrderedDict(
        sorted(
            v.items(),  # "sequences1": {"header1": 3},"sequences2":     {"header2": 5},"sequences3": {"header3": 1}
            key=lambda h: next(  # h is  (sequences1,{"header1": 3})
                iter(
                    h[1].values()  # h[1] is {"header1": 3}
                )
            ),
            reverse=True
        )
    ) for k, v in d.items()}

print(result)
```

output is

```py
{'modID1': OrderedDict([('sequences2', {'header2': 5}), ('sequences1', {'header1': 3}), ('sequences3', {'header3': 1})]), 'modID2': OrderedDict([('sequences2', {'header2': 8}), ('sequences1', {'header1': 1})])}
```

i changed your lambda function from `lambda h: v[seq for seq in v][header]` to `lambda h: next(iter(h[1].values())`

1. `h` is `("sequences", {"header": count})`
2. `h[1]` is `{"header": count}`
3. `next(iter(h[1].values())` first value of {"header": count} [getting first value of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097866/python-access-to-first-element-in-dictionary)
4. first value of `{"header": count}` is `count`

in python 3 `items()` work like  `iteritems()`  [dict.items() and dict.iteritems()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you

Comment: you are welcome. mark as 'answered' mine or AChampion answer,  whichever you like more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the you don't care about the order of the outer dict and just the inner dicts of sequences then you can do this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = {'modID1': {'sequences2':{'header2':5}, 'sequences1':{'header1': 3},
...                    'sequences3':{'header3':1}},
...         'modID2': {'sequences2':{'header2':8},'sequences1':{'header1': 1}}}
>>> {k: OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: -sum(x[1].values()))) 
...  for k, v in data.items()}
{'modID1': OrderedDict([('sequences2', {'header2': 5}), ('sequences1', {'header1': 3}),
                        ('sequences3', {'header3': 1})]),
 'modID2': OrderedDict([('sequences2', {'header2': 8}), ('sequences1', {'header1': 1})])}
```