# Count values of dictionary

Tags: python

I'm having a problem here, its counting the empty lists which must not be counted

Is there a way to not count the empty lists?

```
dic ={None: [[], [], [(3, 2, 0)], [(3, 1, 0)], [], [], [(4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 0)], [(4, 2, 0)]]}
x = list(map(len, dic.values()))
print(x[0])
```

Output Required

```
5
```

My code Outpute

```
8
```

Comment: In you're example I see 4 none empty list and not 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dic.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) wraps all the values from different keys inside another list:

```
>>> dic.values()
[[[], [], [(3, 2, 0)], [(3, 1, 0)], [], [], [(4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 0)], [(4, 2, 0)]]]
```

Since, you have only one key there is only one element in `dic.values()` and when you do `x = list(map(len, dic.values()))` you get `8` because that's the length on the inner list.

You need to iterate over the inner list `dic.values()[0]` and get the length from there:

```
>>> sum(map(len, dic.values()[0]))
5
```

---

**UPDATE:** If you are using python 3, you can get the first value as `list(dic.values())[0]`:

```
>>> sum(map(len, list(dic.values())[0]))
5
```

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097896/2549021) list many ways you can get the first value.

Comment: I'm getting an error TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Comment: It seems you are using python3. Please try `list(dic.values())[0]`