# Accessing random key of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have a dictionary with some keys.

I can access a key by name:

```
my_dict[my_key]
```

Now suppose I want to access one of the keys (no matter which).
I could just list the keys and take the first one.

So the access to this key will look like

```
my_dict[my_dict.keys()[0]]
```

However I'm wondering if I can just directly access the "first" element of a dictionary by just indexing. I know "first" doesn't make sense, but I just mean the first key that `my_dict.keys()` would return.

Something like:

```
my_dict[0]
```

But here instead of taking "the key 0" I want this 0 to be an index.

Why I want this:

Basically all keys have the same structure inside, and I need to get this structure, so any of the keys will work.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I would be happy with a solution either for python2 or python3

Comment: I actually think this question is subtly different. In any case, I added a new solution to the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824551/9209546

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you may find another trick than what you mention i.e. `my_dict[my_dict.keys()[0]]`.

As dictionaries are unordered, I'm not quite sure though what an `index` would mean.

Now, you may want to put that in a `pandas.DataFrame()` using :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
```

Which handles indices.

Now you can indeed do :

```
> df.iloc[0]
```

Comment: This question never mentions `pandas` and does not have `pandas` tag

Comment: That's right but I thought maybe user doesn't know / didn't think of it. In my opinion that seems like a good candidate when considering dicts with index.