# How to sort a dictioary based on its first and second values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries, which are already sorted based on the first values. How do I continue to sort this list based on its second values as well?

Here is my list of dictionaries:

```
[{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P4': [19, 95]}]
```

Desired outcome:

```
[{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P4': [19, 95]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}]
```

I am in the process of completing a Shortest Job First scheduling assignment in Python. The first value of each key(process) is the cpu burst and the second value is the arrival time, so I would need P4 to go before P2 since its arrival time comes first and they have the same cpu burst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, If you want to just sort list of the dictionary with the list values you can use the one line of python code as below:

```
d = [{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}, {'P4': [19, 95]}]  # assign the dictionary value
sort_by_first = sorted(d, key=lambda x: list(x.values()))
```

### Output:

```
[{'P3': [7, 117]}, {'P8': [14, 88]}, {'P4': [19, 95]}, {'P2': [19, 102]}]
```

`sorted()` function in python accepts optional keyword argument `key` where you can pass a custom function to look for the key and I just made a lambda function which will sort list of dictionary `d` by its value list `list(x.values())`

In python list comparison results as follow:

```
In [1]: [19, 95] < [19, 102]
Out[1]: True

In [2]: [19, 95] < [19, 95]
Out[2]: False

In [3]: [19, 95] < [19, 5]
Out[3]: False
```

### Update:

lambda function can be replaced with `lambda x: next(iter(x.values()))` where instead of typecasting value from `dict_values` is extracted as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097896/7664524) answer.

Comment: Please add **some** explanation to your "one line of python code" for the sake of starters

Comment: No need to cast to a list.`lambda x: x.values()` should be enough which will return an iterable anyways

Comment: @mad_ it won't work as key of dictionaries are unknown and hence calling .values() returns `dict_values` which does not support `<` operator

Comment: @Gahan then it should not work by casting as well. Try `d={'a':[1]};
type(d.values())`;d.values() will be a list already. no need to cast. lambda is iterating each element of the `list` which is actually a dict. in your case intermediate `x` is actually a `dict` and `dict.values()` will return all the values contained inside the dict irrespective of keys.

Comment: @mad_ I think you are talking about python 2.x but user explicitly tagged python 3.x and in python 3.x you need to cast dict.values() to list to access values by index

Comment: oh yeah.. using both versions together is a nightmare sometimes because they behave so differently even in small cases. Sorry my bad.Thanks though